# Calculating aggregated field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm back with more potgresql question :)

I have a query that shows the amount of time between when a plan was created and when a plan was updated.

```
select
  ...

  EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(plans.updated_at) - MIN(plans.created_at)) AS DateDifference

  ...
```

Now I would like to exclude the results when the number of days is 0

So I tried:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(plans.updated_at) - MIN(plans.created_at)) > 0
```

But I get Aggregated functions are not allowed in where.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query does what you want, then you would use a `having` clause:

```
HAVING EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(plans.updated_at) - MIN(plans.created_at)) > 0
```

Conditions on aggregated values need to be handled *after* the aggregation.  Hence, the `HAVING` clause goes after the `GROUP BY`.